# File locks support in Docker volumes of NFS4 shares

Tags: docker, nfs, file-locking, docker-volume

Here is an excerpt from my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
volumes:
  nfs_share:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=nfs_server,rw,noatime
      device: ":/srv/nfs_share"
```

The volume is correctly mounted on the host.

However, inside my docker instance, I can not use file locks.

Example:

```
# exec 3 > test_file
# flock -x 3
flock: 3: No locks available
```

If I mount the partition manually on the host, I can use file locks without any problem.

Also, I see that Docker doesn't mount the NFS share with the right protocol version:

```
:/srv/nfs_share on /var/lib/docker/volumes/registry_registry/_data type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr={MYIPADDR},mountvers=3,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr={MYIPADDR})
```

However, if I mount the partition manually on the host, the NFS4 is correctly used:

```
nfs:/srv/nfs_share on /mnt/nfs_share type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr={MYIPADDR},local_lock=none,addr={MYIPADDR})
```

I tried adding `nolock` option, or `local_lock=all`, these options seem to be ignored… I also tried specifying the `vers=4.0` option, or using `type: nfs4`… All these variants don't change anything.

Comment: I still have similar issues. Did you find a solution/workaround? I would be happy about an update

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet. Maybe opening an issue on Docker's github would help.

Comment: For me the nolock option actually worked. But I would like to have the locks working :)

Comment: My workaround was to use NFS on the host machine, and mount the host partition into the docker container. This works, but is a bit ugly.

Comment: For me on ubuntu 16 using `type: nfs4` was _indeed_ the solution, docken then mounted the NFS system with nfs4 (and thus subsequently allowed file locks).

Answer (score 5):

```
volumes:
  nfs-gemstash:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      device: :/nfsdata
      o: addr=nfs_server_ip,rw,nolock
      type: nfs
```

Try this then use the new yaml file to create the container directly.